# Change in child accordion indicator icon twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, accordion

I have two level Twitter bootstrap accordion with drop down indicator icons.
Problem is when i close the sub-group the indicator changes in parent too.
(Sorry about my bad english)

```
$('.accordion-body').on('show', function() {
   $(this).siblings('.accordion-heading').children('.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e').addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
});

$('.accordion-body').on('hide', function() {
   $(this).siblings('.accordion-heading').children('.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s').addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e');
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwNYB/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, it was pretty obscure, but here's the cause: the "show" and "hide" events bubble up by default, so a hide/show event firing in a sub-collapsible was getting catched also by parent collapsibles.

The solution is to tweak the listeners this way:

```
$('.accordion-body').on('show', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    …
}
```

Here a working version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HwNYB/2/.

Sidenote:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

has its IE counterpart:

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
```

Comment: Heading is before, and "prev()" method nothing changes. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Hi, just updated my answer to give solution to the problem. Check it out :)